# Two columns and one footer using css

Tags: css

I want to create a robust css style that works whith almost all browser (included IE7, firefox 3)
that show me two columns and  one footer.
I was trying to implement the following code,
but I have one problem: A and B are not at the same horizontal level.
please halp me to fix the css style.

[Click here for the current example](http://jsfiddle.net/euYTQ/3/).

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">A</div>
  <div class="right">B</div>
  <div class="footer">C</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.container {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #9999CC;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 750px;
}
.left{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #99CC99;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
.right {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #9999CC;
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
}
.footer {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #CCCC99;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: There is a typo in your left div...change 'clas' to 'class'

Comment: this is a stupid mistake!! I need one COFFEE CUP please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/euYTQ/6/

You're missing an s in `class`.

Answer (score 1):

Change `<div clas="left">` to `<div class="left">`.

:)